# Row selection in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I want to show the current date on selecting the row of UIDatePickerView on the label, My issue is when I opened my date picker it doesn't show anything on the label on selecting the row but when I move my date picker view, It started updating my label, I am not able to fix it. I want to display the date whenever I touch the date picker view row. I even added TouchUpInside row method also, still, it is not working

Here is my code snippet:

```
- (IBAction)btn_calendar_event:(id)sender {
    // ADD UIDatePicker and open it
    if (self.picker) {
        [self.toolbar removeFromSuperview];
        [self.picker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [self hideKeyboard];
    self.picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    self.picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.picker setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:@"textColor"];

    self.picker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.picker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

[self.picker addTarget:self action:@selector(dueDateChanged:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.picker addTarget:self action:@selector(dueDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
     }

```
// dueDateChanged method 

-(void) dueDateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];

    NSLog(@"Picked the date %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]]);
   _txtf_birthDate.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]];

}

// Done button Action 

-(void)onDoneButtonClick {
    [self dueDateChanged :  self.picker];
    [self.toolbar removeFromSuperview];
    [self.picker removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you're initialising your picker your picker is not settings the date to label so it'll only update when dueDateChanged will be triggered so when you initialise your date picker select the date you want to display as a default date and show it in label like

After `[self.picker addTarget:self action:@selector(dueDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]` Simply add a default date to your picker like :-

```
self.picker.date=[NSDate date]; // add the default initial date
[self dueDateChanged:self.picker];
```

According to your requirement "If I want to display the current date on selecting row then how to do it, It is now setting default initial date without even selecting the row of date picker view
" you can add this line anywhre from where you want to show the date

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
_txtf_birthDate.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: I want to display the date only when date picker pops up and when I select the row of date picker, It is resolving the issue of showing current date but before my date picker could pop up it is setting the date without even touching the row of date picker!!!

Comment: just remove 'self.picker.date=[NSDate date]' if you dont want to set the date : )

Comment: The above code which you have shared is displaying the date without even touching the picker, I want to select the date on touching the picker view

Comment: unfortunately  buddy there delegates provided by the date picker you'll have to create a custom button or tapgesturerecognizer and add it to your view when the picker appear to get the touch.